# Voice Memos fails when trying to share a recording

Tags: iphone, sharing, voice-memo

A voice memo plays fine but when trying to share it, it fails with the message "Preparing Failed.  New Recording ## is being optimized for sharing at this time."

After waiting for hours and finally closing and re-opening the app, it continues to have this issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can share Voice Memos?

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by duplicating the recording and then sharing the duplicate.

To do this, click the ellipsis `…` next to it and choose "Duplicate", then share the duplicate and it should work.